# Editing search query if token not null - Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'am trying to add information to my search query in splunk if a token is not null but is not working.
I have an input checkbox called filtre, and I want to modify my search if the input filtre is used.

so, I want to do this

```
if $filtre$ == null  
index="fortigate" policyid=$policy$  $scr_dest$=$IP$  service=$service$ NOT action = blocked
| stats  values(src_ip) values(dest_ip) values(service) values(action)
else:
index="fortigate" policyid=$policy$  $scr_dest$=$IP$  service=$service$ NOT action = blocked
| stats  values(src_ip) values(dest_ip) values(service) values(action) by  $filtre$
```

I have been trying `by *` `by null` , using eval and multisearch

```
| multisearch 
[search index="fortigate" policyid=$policy$  $scr_dest$=$IP$  service=$service$ NOT action = blocked
| stats  values(src_ip) values(dest_ip) values(service) values(action)
| where like($filtre$ == null ) ]
[search index="fortigate" policyid=$policy$  $scr_dest$=$IP$  service=$service$ NOT action = blocked 
| stats values(src_ip) values(dest_ip) values(service) values(action) by $filtre$
| | where like($filtre$ !=null) ]
```

Nothing works.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The command `where like($filtre$ == null)` is incorrect.  The `like` function compares a field value to a SQL pattern and expects two arguments rather than a single boolean expression.  To determine if a field is or isn't null, use the `isnull()` or `isnotnull()` function.

Using `stats ... by $filtre$` will fail when the token is empty because the field required by `by` will be absent.  To fix that, we have to make `by` go away when $filtre$ is null, which can be done using a separate token.

When the filtre token is set, define another token (which I'll call $by$) and use that in the `stats` command.  When $filtre$ is cleared, unset $by$.

```
<input type="checkbox" token="filtre">
  ...
  <change>
    <condition match="$filtre$==&quot;Enable&quot;">
      <set token="by">by $filtre$</set>
    </condition>
    <condition>
      <set token="by"> </unset>
    </condition>
  </change>
</input>
```

`| stats ... values(action) $by$`

Comment: Hi RichG, I tried that, but isn't working, splunk is always in " Search is waiting for input.."

Comment: It would do that because $by$ is not set.  I've corrected the code in my answer.